# Would doing GPU accelerated PCA in R for "fat" data matrices be worth the effort or should I stick with the standard routines?

Tags: r, pca, svd, gpu

I'm aware that *princomp* in R used *eigen* on the correlation or covariance matrix, as determined by *cor* and the prcomp routine is based on the *svd*.

```
> princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)$loadings    
Loadings:
         Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
Murder   -0.536  0.418 -0.341  0.649
Assault  -0.583  0.188 -0.268 -0.743
UrbanPop -0.278 -0.873 -0.378  0.134
Rape     -0.543 -0.167  0.818       

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00

> prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
Standard deviations:
[1] 1.5748783 0.9948694 0.5971291 0.4164494

Rotation:
                PC1        PC2        PC3         PC4
Murder   -0.5358995  0.4181809 -0.3412327  0.64922780
Assault  -0.5831836  0.1879856 -0.2681484 -0.74340748
UrbanPop -0.2781909 -0.8728062 -0.3780158  0.13387773
Rape     -0.5434321 -0.1673186  0.8177779  0.08902432

> svd(cor(USArrests))$u    
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.5358995  0.4181809 -0.3412327  0.64922780
[2,] -0.5831836  0.1879856 -0.2681484 -0.74340748
[3,] -0.2781909 -0.8728062 -0.3780158  0.13387773
[4,] -0.5434321 -0.1673186  0.8177779  0.08902432

> eigen(cor(USArrests))$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.5358995  0.4181809 -0.3412327  0.64922780
[2,] -0.5831836  0.1879856 -0.2681484 -0.74340748
[3,] -0.2781909 -0.8728062 -0.3780158  0.13387773
[4,] -0.5434321 -0.1673186  0.8177779  0.08902432
```

I've also read that one could also use the QR decomposition to do PCA but I have yet to come across an R implementation. (If anyone would be kind enough to show how it's done that would be great.)

I'm looking to apply PCA for "fat" data matrices (number of columns greater than the number of rows) and was wondering if the routines could be further optimized under GPU (nvidia) routines under R preferably without writing custom C/C++ CUDA code.

Looking at the packages gpuR, gputools, and gmatrix;

- gpuR only supports svd and covariance for symmetric matrices since it is dependent on OpenCL
- gputools support QR only but it has functions for correlation, not sure if non-symmetric matries are excluded for both
- it seems only gmatrix  has GPU (with CUDA) support for both SVD and QR decompositions without an explicit symmetric matrix requirement.

Would there be any benefit if I do PCA based on GPU(nvidia)-based svd and/or qr decomposition routines for "fat" data matrices or should I just focus on the standard routines provided by base R?

Comment: The only way to answer your question is to run a benchmark and see if it worth it.  If you have a device I recommend trying it out and reporting them or problems here once you give it a try.